# How to find Common element in row in data frame in python27

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have one data frame containing many rows, I want to find a common element in the row and min max in that row, I am not able to find any inbuilt function for that.

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4],'col3':[2,1,3]})
print df`

in row0  col2 and col3 having a common element as 2

in row2  col1 and col3 having a common element as 3

is there any function to find a common element in a row and min max in that row also

Hii, I have one more Question

I have n number of columns in data frame, And i want to concatenate column 1 to column 1 by data frames, how can i do it more efficiently.

Currently i am using following method , showing only for 3 data frames can u please show me how to do if we have n number of columns

```
    import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4],'col3':[4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4],'col3':[4,5,6]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4],'col3':[4,5,6]})

dfcol1 = pd.concat([df1.iloc[:, 0:1], df2.iloc[:, 0:1], df3.iloc[:, 0:1]],axis=1)
dfcol2 = pd.concat([df1.iloc[:, 1:2], df2.iloc[:, 1:2], df3.iloc[:, 1:2]],axis=1)
dfcol3 = pd.concat([df1.iloc[:, 2:3], df2.iloc[:, 2:3], df3.iloc[:, 2:3]],axis=1)

print dfcol1
print dfcol2
print dfcol3
```

Output expected:

```
   col1  col1  col1
0     1     1     1
1     2     2     2
2     3     3     3
   col2  col2  col2
0     2     2     2
1     3     3     3
2     4     4     4
   col3  col3  col3
0     4     4     4
1     5     5     5
2     6     6     6
```

Can anyone tell me more efficient way to do the same as above for n number of columns ?

Comment: what's your sample output?

Comment: Some problem in answer?

Comment: Can you please tell me one more efficient way as asked above

Comment: @Chetan.B - Check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no function for common values, so need create it:

```
def f(x):
    s = x.value_counts()
    val = s[s > 1]
    #return one common value if exist 
    return np.nan if val.empty else val.index[0]

a = df.apply(f, 1)
b = df.max(axis=1)
c = df.min(axis=1)

df = pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1, keys=('first_same', 'max','min'))
print (df)
   first_same  max  min
0         2.0    2    1
1         NaN    3    1
2         3.0    4    3
```

If multiple columns and possible more common values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4],'col3':[2,1,3],'col4':[1,1,3]})
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     2     1
1     2     3     1     1
2     3     4     3     3

def f(x):
    s = x.value_counts()
    val = s[s > 1]
    #return all common values in list
    return np.nan if val.empty else val.index.tolist()

a = df.apply(f, 1)
b = df.max(axis=1)
c = df.min(axis=1)

df = pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1, keys=('common', 'max','min'))
print (df)
   common  max  min
0  [2, 1]    2    1
1     [1]    3    1
2     [3]    4    3
```

EDIT:

For create multiple `DataFrame`s your solution is nice, but better is more dynamic:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfcol1 = pd.concat([x.iloc[:, 0] for x in dfs],axis=1)
print (dfcol1)
   col1  col1  col1
0     1     1     1
1     2     2     2
2     3     3     3

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfcol2 = pd.concat([x.iloc[:, 1] for x in dfs],axis=1)
print (dfcol2)
   col2  col2  col2
0     2     2     2
1     3     3     3
2     4     4     4
```

EDIT1:

If each DataFrame have same colums names is possible use:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfall = pd.concat(dfs, keys=('a','b','c'), axis=1)
print (dfall)
     a              b              c          
  col1 col2 col3 col1 col2 col3 col1 col2 col3
0    1    2    4    1    2    4    1    2    4
1    2    3    5    2    3    5    2    3    5
2    3    4    6    3    4    6    3    4    6

dfcol1 = dfall.xs('col1', axis=1, level=1)
print (dfcol1)
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
```

Comment: Say if i have 100 columns then i have to use                                     dfcol1 = pd.concat([x.iloc[:, 0] for x in dfs],axis=1)          this 100 times i want to make this dynamic

Comment: @Chetan.B - I think if have 100 dataframes and from each need first column only.

Comment: @Chetan.B - there is 100 DataFrames with same structure? Same columns names?

Comment: Input data frames = 3 having 100 columns each >> output data frames =100 having 3 columns each

Comment: @Chetan.B - I modify answer, please check it.

Comment: @Chetan.B - You are welcome! Small friend advice - in future better is create new question :)

Answer (score 0):

Transpose the dataframe and then use the inbuilt functions.

```
>>>df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     2
1     2     3     1
2     3     4     3
>>>df.T.describe()

              0    1         2
count  3.000000  3.0  3.000000
mean   1.666667  2.0  3.333333
std    0.577350  1.0  0.577350
min    1.000000  1.0  3.000000
25%    1.500000  1.5  3.000000
50%    2.000000  2.0  3.000000
75%    2.000000  2.5  3.500000
max    2.000000  3.0  4.000000

>>>df.T.min()
0    1
1    1
2    3

>>>df.T.max()
0    2
1    3
2    4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below. This returns the most common element in each row of dataframe. If no common element, this returns a random element from the row.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4],'col3':[2,1,3]}) 
print(df.T.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).idxmax())

# 0    2
# 1    1                                                    
# 2    3                                                     
# dtype: int64
```

To find `max` of each row:

```
df.max(axis=1)
```

To find `min` of each row:

```
df.min(axis=1)
```